# ISNULL not working in TSQL Select

Tags: t-sql, select, isnull

I have a TSQL SELECT that can return a null.  I tried using ISNULL to replace it with 0 but for some reason it is not working.  The table selecting from has the following columns:

- storeID --> int
- penaltyPercent --> decimal(9,2)
- penaltyDate --> dateTime

```sql
SELECT  ISNULL(penaltyPercent, 0.0) AS penaltyPercent  
FROM    dbo.Penalty  
WHERE   (penaltyDate = (SELECT     MAX(penaltyDate) AS date  
                        FROM       dbo.Penalty AS Penalty_1  
                        WHERE      (penaltyDate <= @date) AND (storeID = @storeID))) AND
        (storeID = @storeID)
```

When the date is before the first penalty date (when there should be 0 penalty), no result is returned.  Not sure why this doesn't work.  I have a work around but it is bugging me.

Here is a sample of the data being used:

```
storeID  penaltyDate             penaltyPercent  
182      10/1/2008 12:00:00 AM   0.020000  
182      11/1/2008 12:00:00 AM   0.040000  
182      12/1/2008 12:00:00 AM   0.070000
```

Comment: format your answer, it is clearly in that way

Comment: Thanks everyone, from a relative SQL noob.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you say "When the date is before the first penalty date", do you mean when the value of `@date` is less than the value returned from this query?

```
SELECT MIN(penaltyDate)
FROM Penalty
```

Because then your inner query is going to return null, and (if you're using ANSI nulls) this part will return false,

```
WHERE (penaltyDate = ...
```

Because comparisons with null always return null. So instead of selecting one row with a null value, you're selecting no rows.

Addendum:

To confirm this is the problem, change your outer query's first line to

```
SELECT ISNULL(MAX(penaltyPercent),0.0) AS penaltyPercent
```

It will work because of what I've described above.

Comment: The inner query doesn't return null, it returns an empty result set.

Comment: @P Daddy: I tested it out with SQL Server 2000. To my surprise, it does actually return null in this situation. I expected the inner query to return no records, but it returns null. The outer query returns no records, though.

Answer (score 2):

If @date < penaltyDate, then there is no row returned, so there is no value for ISNULL to act upon.  You might want to select the penalty percent into a variable, and then select out to the result set `ISNULL(@pentaltyPercent)`.

Answer (score 0):

Do you acctually have data that it's date is before the first penaly date? If your query doesn't return records, your IsNull clause will do anything because it works against anything.